# Disable button if element contains class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable my button if any of my `.Info` `div` contains `<i>` tag contains a specific class. I am trying to do it, but nothing works for me.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Info").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    if ($("i.fa fa-times").length > 0) {
      $('#jsbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#jsbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="info">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="jsbutton">Add Purchase Order</button>
```

Comment: What do you expect the `change` event to do when bind on a `div` element? Despite it being `.Info` instead of `.info`

Comment: Can you elaborate on when which condition should be met to disable the button?

Comment: Look at the [docs for the change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) - `div` doesn't ever fire a change event. Some basic debugging should tell you that your event handler never gets fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("div.info").find("i").hasClass("fa fa-times"))
    {
        $('#jsbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  
    }
    else
    {

        $('#jsbutton').prop("disabled", false);
    }

});
</script>
```

Hope, this may be helpful for you.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to hide disabled button?

Comment: @DUbaicos it's because this code only runs once when the site loads

Answer (score 1):

when does 'info' change?

if any should contain 'i' then it doesn't matter who...

```
if( document.querySelectorAll('i').length ) jsbutton.disabled = true
```

or more simple

```
jsbutton.disabled = document.querySelectorAll('i').length
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery has the [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) for such a thing

```
if ( $('.i').hasClass( "fa fa-times" ) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($(".info").find("i.fa").length >= 0) {
        $("#jsbutton").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure the `info` class is lowercase.

```
$('.info').on('click', function(e) {
```

You need a dot before your `fa-times` times class in the selector.

```
if ($('i.fa.fa-times').length > 0) // if ($('i').hasClass('fa-times'))
```

### Demo

```js
$(function() {
  $('.info').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($('i').hasClass('fa-times')) {
      $('#jsbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#jsbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.info:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="info">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="jsbutton">Add Purchase Order</button>
```